# #9 challenge - Learn Your Node (Async Callback)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynccallback

I'm struggling on this particular challenge:

Exercise 9 - Juggling Async

> You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the URLs and print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to print out the length, just the data as a String; one line per URL. The catch is that you must print them out in the same order as the URLs are provided to you as command-line arguments.

Here's my code:

```js
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl')
var results = [];
var count = 0

function getURLs() {
  var urls = []
  for(var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++){
    urls.push(process.argv[i]);
  }
  return urls
}

function getHTTP(url){
  http.get(url, function(response){
    response.pipe(bl(function(err,data){
      if(err){return console.error(err)}
      results[count] = data.toString();
      count ++;
      if (count === process.argv.length - 2){
        printAll()
      }
    }))
  })
}

function printAll(){
  for(var i = 0 ; i < results.length; i++){
    console.log(results[i])
  }
}

function start(){
  retrivedURL = getURLs()
  for(var i = 0; i < retrivedURL.length; i++){
    getHTTP(retrivedURL[i])
  }
}

start()
```

I can't seem to figure out where it is wrong--it is outputting in the order of the URL that is retrieved.

Comment: You cannot use loops and async functions like that and expect the order to be maintained, you need to sequence the async calls asynchronously. One way with continuation passing style is by using recursion instead of a loop. Another option is to sequence using promises.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async.eachSeries for this purpose i.e to make this URLs calls async. It is well explained [here](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md).